# Raphael transform not working?

Tags: raphael, transform

I have this code in Raphael:

```
var myrect = paper.rect(10,10, 25,25);
```

The rectangle appears.

When I add this code:

```
myrect.transform(T200,0);
```

...nothing happens.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong, please? These Raphael transforms don't seem to be working for me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that Element.transform takes a string as a parameter.

Try:

```
myrect.transform("t200,0");
```

And see if that makes any difference.

Source:
http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.transform

Comment: I tried adding the transform as an attribute to a path and it worked:

myPath.attr({ "stroke-width": "2",
        "fill": "#E5EDD8", 
        "stroke": "#272424",
        "stroke-linecap": "round",
        "stroke-linejoin": "round",
        "stroke-miterlimit": "10",
        "transform": "T370,370"});